# Why does this groovy code work differently in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline

I've got a piece of code that works perfectly in all of the groovy interpreters I know of, including Jenkins scripting console. Yet it has a weird behavior when it comes to pipeline scripts.

```
def kvs = ['key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2']
println kvs
println kvs.inject(''){ s,k,v -> s+= "{'$k': '$v' } "}
```

First of all, the map is printed differently:

- **Expected**: `[key1:value1, key2:value2]`
- **Got**: `{key1=value1, key2=value2}`

Then, more of a problem, the yielded result differs drastically:

- **Expected**: `{'key1': 'value1' } {'key2': 'value2' }`
- **Got**: `null`

Both of these results were obtained with the following groovy version: `2.4.12`.
(Though, outside of the pipeline script, I also tried versions `2.4.6` and `2.4.15` and always got the expected results)

Please note that I am not interested in workarounds. I only wish to understand why the behavior changed from normal groovy to pipeline script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because the Jenkins pipeline code is not actually running this Groovy code directly it is interpreting it with a parser to apply script security to keep the Jenkins system secure amongst other things. To quote "Pipeline code is written as Groovy but the execution model is radically transformed at compile-time to Continuation Passing Style (CPS)." - see best practices https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/. In short, don't write complex Groovy code in your pipelines - try to use standard steps supplied by the pipeline DSL or plugins. Simple Groovy code in script sections can be useful in some scenarios however. Nowadays I am putting some of my more complex stuff in plugins that supply custom steps.

Comment: I thought it might be that. Still I'm surprised.  
Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes it caught me out a number of times!